# Aurora Postgres Connection Timeout Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

This was working the last time I looked at it. The code remains unchanged.

I have an SSH tunnel through an ec2 instance to an Aurora Postgres DB. I can connect to it through psql. I can also connect to it through Datagrip. I'm able to run queries.

But using the exact same connection settings through nodejs I get a connection timeout. The connection settings are exactly the same as the ones I'm using in psql and Datagrip.

```
pool = new Pool({
    user: "myuser",
    host: "localhost",
    database: 'somedb',
    password: "password",
    port: 1234
});

pool.query('SELECT column1, column2 FROM test ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        response.status(400).send(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
})
```

The same code works on the server directly. It just no longer works when trying to connect via ssh tunnel. (although it used to work)

Comment: I doubt there is any problem with your code, it would more likely be running into security problems. You should be running your db in a private subnet and hopefully tunneling through a bastian for Datagrip. Is your function being run in your VPC?

Comment: Yes db is running in a private subnet. I am tunneling through a bastion. I am connecting locally via ssh tunnel to test. I successfully connect via Datagrip. Just can't connect via code. Although it used to work.

Comment: To be clear I do not have a problem with the code running on AWS. Just my local dev.

Comment: Can you quote the exact timeout error message?  Can you use the tunnel with psql *after* node.js has already failed on it (i.e. the tunnel hasn't collapsed)?

Comment: "Connection terminated due to connection timeout."

Yes I can still use psql after nodejs has failed. The connection is still good in Datagrip and I can still run queries.

Tried disabling my firewall just in case and have checked the connection settings in my app many times.

Comment: Local dev won't typically have the tunneling available that Datagrip has in it. If your db is in a private subnet you'll need it.

Comment: I'm tunneling from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of the pg npm package. I updated to a newer package and the connection started working again.